# VS2010 loses Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution which has mixed .net framework. 
Environment(in solution) : Website 3.5 Framwork 
                           Class Library 2.0 Framwork
                 another   Class Library 3.5 Framwork

I have added another class library with 3.5 framwork to use LINQ to SQL 
add new item linq-to-sql and then added reference to website . once I have added this additional classLibrary with linq-to-sql my intellisense is lost. Even it doesn't recongnise txtBox in the markup. I can only include stadard data types like string , int etc..(If I force using Ctrl+spacebar).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are probably quite a few reasons why this could happen. According to [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/5ae00716-d9e5-4667-ae16-80f69e7c9556) there is something called "Low-Impact Intellisense" which can be toggled on and off by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Space.